# Redirect 301 with wordpress articles from a domain to another

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

my client changed his wordpress website to a new domain.
I tried with the htaccess to redirect 301 the articles dynamicaly but it's not working.

The URL format of articles are : /%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/

I put this in htaccess but not working :

```
redirect 301 /([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/(.*)/ http://www.newdomain.com/$1/$2/$3/$4/
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks

EDIT:
This is my actual .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([\w\-]+)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1/$2/$3/$4/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use mod_rewrite for this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/([\w\-]+)/?$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1/$2/$3/$4/ [R=302,NC,L]
```

If you are happy with the redirect, and would like to make it permanent, you can change `302` to `301`.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work. I edit my question with my actual htaccess.

Comment: You need to move the rule just below your `RewriteBase`, otherwise it won't work.